# Computer Science: Java MC

Tags: java

```
private int[] myStuff;
/** Precondition: myStuff contains int values in no particular order.
  /*/ 
public int mystery(int num)
{
    for (int k = myStuff.length-1; k>=0; k--)
    {
        if (myStuff[k] < num)
        {
           return k;
        }
    }
return -1;
}
```

Which of the following best describes the contents of myStuff after the 
following statement has been executed?

```
int m = mystery(n);
```

Answer: All values in positions m+1 through myStuff.length-1 are 
greater than or equal to n.

Can anyone explain why this answer is correct? I'm not sure what they mean by contents but, I concluded that myStuff is unchanged because the code doesn't alter the value of myStuff.

Comment: Your "following statement" simply isn't valid Java. It's hard to tell what you're asking here.

Comment: Your for loop won't compile either.  You should get the method to compile in an IDE and step through it with a debugger.

Comment: I fixed it. For some reason random characters were added when copying and pasting the code from a pdf file.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but, this exact question was on an AP Exam a few years ago.

Comment: `myStuff` is unchanged. You need to look at what value the `mystery` function returns and the condition upon which it exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question about **the content** is valid. It has nothing to with whether the content itself was changed.

This method returns either a non-negative number when there is such `k` (from `myStuff.length-1` to `0`) that `myStuff[k]` is less than `n`,  or `-1` when **all** elements of `myStuff` are more than or equal to `n`.

Let's consider **both** cases:

- m is non-negative number - it means that position `m` was the last **from the right** that satisfied the condition `myStaff[m] < n`, your answer is correct
- m is `-1` - it means that all elements are more than equal than `m+1` (which in this case is `0`) - hence the answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

Precondition says, that **myStuff** contains integer values in no particular order. The for loop is initialized with **k** equal to the lenght of **myStuff** minus one (since array indices start at zero), iterates while **k** is greater than or equal to zero and subtract one from **k** in each iteration.

If you look at the **if** statement, it will return the current value of **k**, when the value at the corresponding index of **myStuff[k]** is less than **n**; hence all values in array indices greater than the returned value plus one, must be greater than or equal to **n**. And if no numbers integers in **myStuff** are greater than **n**, minus one is returned.

I hope this helps.

Btw - you're right that the content of **mySyuff** isn't changed.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that `myStuff` is unchanged. However, they are asking about the relationship between the data in the array, the return value of the function, and the function's arguments.

The code does the following:

- Iterates the array in reverse order. (for loop)
- At each index during the iteration, it checks the value of that index against `n`, returning the current index if `n` is larger. (if statement)

So what does the method return?  It returns the first index from the end where `mystuff[m] < n`. (`mystuff[i] >= num`)